# How to popup checkbox values using Angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am trying to find a way to get the checkbox values from a form and show it to the user in view mode. I have tried some code but I am getting errors in the console that "can't read property 'push' and 'toString()'".

add-customer.component.ts

```
public otherIncomes = [
        { code: 1, displayValue: 'RENTAL_INCOME', selected: false },
        { code: 2, displayValue: 'PARTNERSHIP_IN_BUSINESS', selected: false},
        { code: 3, displayValue: 'INVESTMENT_PROCEEDS', selected: false },
        { code: 0, displayValue: 'OTHER', selected: false },
];

const arrIncomeSources = popupData.CustomerEntity.otherIncomeSource.toString().**split**(',');
                this.otherIncomes.forEach(element => {
                    const idx = arrIncomeSources.findIndex(x => +x === element.code);
                    this.sourcesOfOtherIncome.**push**(new FormControl(idx >= 0));
                });
```

add-customer-account-information.component.html

```
<div class="mx-3" *ngFor="let income of sourcesOfIncome" >
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="incomeSources" value="income.code">
                    {{localizationService.language[income.displayValue] }}
        </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

add-customer.component.ts

```
this.cusAccInfoTabFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    incomeSources: this.sourcesOfOtherIncome,
 });
```

Comment: First thing first, can we check if:
1. `popupData.CustomerEntity.otherIncomeSource` is not `null` or `undefined`? Don't forget to check `popupData.CustomerEntity` as well.
2. Have `this.sourcesOfOtherIncome` being initiated? You can do that in the constructor to be `[]` if you want

Comment: yes, I checked **popupData.CustomerEntity.otherIncomeSource** and it is not null. sourcesofOtherIncome initiated as ` public sourcesOfOtherIncome = new FormArray([]);` @GabrielGeorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add-customer-account-information.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="incomeSources">
        <div class="mx-3" *ngFor="let income of incomeSources.controls; let i=index">
          <mat-checkbox [formControl]="income">
            {{ localizationService.language[sourcesOfIncome[i].displayValue] }}
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
</div>
```

add-customer-account-information.component.ts

```
@Input() public addCustomerAccountInformationFormGroup: FormGroup;
    public get incomeSources(): any {
            if (this.addCustomerAccountInformationFormGroup) {
                return this.addCustomerAccountInformationFormGroup.get('incomeSources').value;
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use formArrayName to handle arrays.

```
<div [formGroup]="cusAccInfoTabFormGroup">
    <div formArrayName="incomeSources">
        <div>
             <div *ngFor="let s of incomeSources.controls; let i = index" 
              [formGroupName]="i">
             here you can add your fields ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in ts:

```
get incomeSources(): FormArray{
    return this.cusAccInfoTabFormGroup.get('incomeSources') as FormArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer solved my problem.